# Redirect to login page, if not logged in with AngularFire 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

Whats the best way to redirect the user to the login page, if he's not authenticated with Angular2 / AngularFire2?

For example; I want to protect the **/dashboard** page from not authenticated users. The user should instantly get redirected to the **/login** page,

I'm using

- **angular2** version 2.0.0-rc.1
- **angular2/router** version 2.0.0-rc.1
- **firebase** version 3.0.5
- **angularfire2** version 2.0.0-beta.1

Comment: What Angular2 version, what router version?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer oh sorry, forgot that. angular2 version 2.0.0-rc.1 and angular2/router version 2.0.0-rc.1, firebase version 3.0.5,  angularfire2 version 2.0.0-beta.1

Comment: This router is deprecated as well. Either stick with `@angular/router` or migrate to the new V3 alpha.7 router. You can use guards with the new router where you do checks and then redirect.

Comment: Alright. I actually thin I'm currently using the newest version because I just create the project with `ng create <project-name>`. But anyway, my only question now is, how do I check if the user is Authenticated with Firebase? I assume with the AngularFire Provider (`af.auth.XXX`)? @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can protect urls using Angular 2's UI router guard conditions. 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

An example using firebase

**Guard Component**

Note it would probably be better to replace referencing AF here, with an authentication service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    user;
    constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {
        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.user = user;
            } else {
                this.user = undefined;
            }
        });
    }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.user) {
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
   }
}
```

**Application Routes**

```
import { CanActivateViaAuthGuard} from './CanActivateViaAuthGuard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '/Login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard]}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**Finally the login code**

```
onSubmit() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
    }).then(() => {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', this.dashboard]);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Auth method here.

```
if ($scope.auth === null) {
  $state.go('login');
}
```

Inject your $firebaseAuth and assign it to the  $scope.auth then let the if check of its true or false

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but I'm asking for AngularFire2, not 1 :)

Comment: This is angularfire 2, oh now i see you mean angular 2

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Thanks to [todo-angular-2](https://github.com/r-park/todo-angular2-firebase/blob/master/src/core/auth/auth-route-helper.ts) from r-park

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { AuthService } from './auth-service';


let appInjector: ReflectiveInjector;

/**
 * This is a workaround until `CanActivate` supports DI
 * @see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112
 */

export class AuthRouteHelper {
  static dependencies(): {auth: AuthService, router: Router} {
    const injector: ReflectiveInjector = AuthRouteHelper.injector();
    const auth: AuthService = injector.get(AuthService);
    const router: Router = injector.get(Router);
    return {auth, router};
  }

  static injector(injector?: ReflectiveInjector): ReflectiveInjector {
    if (injector) appInjector = injector;
    return appInjector;
  }

  static requireAuth(): boolean {
    const { auth, router } = AuthRouteHelper.dependencies();
    if (!auth.authenticated) router.navigate(['/SignIn']);
    return auth.authenticated;
  }

  static requireUnauth(): boolean {
    const { auth, router } = AuthRouteHelper.dependencies();
    if (auth.authenticated) router.navigate(['/Tasks']);
    return !auth.authenticated;
  }
}
```